# Google pagespeed shows render-blocking even moving into body part

Tags: javascript, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I just checked this website with Google pagespeed Insights, they asked me change the Javascript block into `body` instead of `head` even this part has been moved already.

Anyone please help me investigate this problem if Google give me a wrong message, or how to fix the kind of issues.

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=en&url=http%3A%2F%2Flogin.di.se%2F%3FappId%3Ddi.se%26lc%3Dsv&tab=mobile

The website
http://login.di.se/?appId=di.se&lc=sv

[image]

I also have another website with same DOM, however don't have this problem with google pagespeed

http://account.sydsvenskan.se/?appId=sydsvenskan.se&lc=sv

Answer (score 1):

**Possibility 1**

Some content loads at the end of page load i.e giving an illusion that preceding JavaScripts were holding back the content rendering.

I see these two images are called in the end only for the site with issue -

```
http://login.di.se/public/images/di/background.jpg
http://login.di.se/public/images/di/checkbox_cust.png
```

You can see this here - http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/bRcsEc/http://login.di.se/?appId=di.se&lc=sv

But this is not the case for your other website - http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/cH2ghk/http://account.sydsvenskan.se/?appId=sydsvenskan.se&lc=sv

**Alternate Solution - Use Asynchronous Load**

Try loading the JavaScript asynchronously as google suggests something like this -

```
<script async src="my.js">
```

Refer - https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS

Comment: Thanks, I just update the question with another website which has same DOM, however doesn't have this problem with Google pagespeed.

http://account.sydsvenskan.se/?appId=sydsvenskan.se&lc=sv

Comment: @KhoiNguyen - are both the endpoints on the same server? and did you try the asyn tag?

Comment: No, they are different servers

Comment: @KhoiNguyen - I have added another theory to the answer, give that a shot.

Comment: Thanks, @Nitish Dhar, however my javascript is requireJs so it's unable to async because we need this file is loaded firstly

Comment: As the message from Google pagespeed, require.min.js is render-blocking, not 2 images as your suggestion

Comment: @KhoiNguyen - did you try testing without those two images that are loaded after require & other js. Just to pin point the issue, remove those images from use in code.

Comment: @KhoiNguyen - I also said that, the require js is blocking the rendering of those two images that load in the end, thus google giving you that error. So if you to test remove using those images or somehow load them before these scripts are loaded, I believe the issue will get resolved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54515/discussion-between-nitish-dhar-and-khoi-nguyen).

Answer (score 0):

There is still a huge chunk of JavaScript in your `<head>`

Also check to see if Cloudflare isn't inadvertently adding JavaScript where it shouldn't